# Question about how to add rows to sqlite database in app without altering unique changes from each user's interaction with their copy of the database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on an app that would have a database of information. The functionality would be the user would look up entries and could save it to a personal list.

My thinking for how this would work would be that the SQLite database would have two tables, one for the information and one for the personal list.

When the user presses the button to save the info to their list a method is called that creates a personal list object and copies the info held in each field of the selected data to the identical field in the personal list object.

And so that the user knows it has been saved it appears differently like labeled that they have already been saved to the personal list. To do this that it has been saved to the list there would be a variable to keep track of that. Default like this.

```
var isSavedToList = false;
```

And when the method is called to save it to the personal list this variable is changed to true.

**My question is: Can I add rows to the SQLite database (after the app has been launched and people are using it) without changing the isSavedToList variables on each users device? Since each person's list is going to be different I don't want them to be reset if I update the database with new entries.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I presume you mean you're doing some kind of program update that adds new rows to the main table. Add your new rows with "isSavedToLiat" set to false (because they can't possibly be set to true because they are new and the user doesn't know about them")